# How can I compare each object with each?

Tags: python, django

How can I compare each object with each and if ratio() > 0.7 set `possible_duplicate=True` for both objects?

My try:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher


class Item(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   desc = models.TextField()
   possible_duplicate = models.BooleanField(default=False)



items = Item.objects.all()

for item in items:
    obj = Item.objects.get(pk=item.pk)
    similarity = SequenceMatcher(None, item.desc, obj.desc).ratio()
    if similarity > 0.7:
        item.possible_duplicate = True
        item.save()
        obj.possible_duplicate = True
        obj.save()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get comparison combinations:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> items = [1, 2, 3]
>>> itertools.combinations(items, 2)  # 2 -> yields tuples with 2 items
<itertools.combinations object at 0x7f5e456d5ba8>
>>> list(itertools.combinations(items, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

---

```
import itertools

items = Item.objects.all()

for item1, item2 in itertools.combinations(items, 2):
    similarity = SequenceMatcher(None, item1.desc, item2.desc).ratio()
    if similarity > 0.7:
        for item in item1, item2:
            item.possible_duplicate = True
            item.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are comparing the object to itself. To compare all objects with each other you can use `itertools.combinations`

```
items_list = list(Items.objects.all())

for a,b in itertools.combinations(items_list, 2):
    similarity = SequenceMatcher(None, a.desc, b.desc).ratio()
    if similarity > 0.7:
        a.possible.duplicate = True
        a.save()
        b.possible.duplicate = True
        b.save()
```

Comment: Why convert `Items.objects.all()` to  a list?

Comment: Maybe not necessary, I just wasn't sure if `itertools.combinations` can handle querysets.

Comment: The first argument to `itertools.combinations` must be an `iterable` and  queryset is iterable thus you don't need to convert it to a list.